# Uname gives unfamiliar timestamp for kernel

Tags: kernel, software-installation

I'm recompiling a new kernel (adding some debugging info) on Ubuntu by doing the following:

```
make vmlinux; make install;
```

after this I do a reboot and select my new custom kernel from the list. However, when I do:

```
uname -a
```

I get a timestamp that doesn't correspond to the last time I built the kernel. When I look in /boot not a single file in there matches up with this timestamp. Also, my changes aren't showing up in the log files. What could be going on here?! Thanks!

Comment: What is the time stamp? Does it roughly match with the time you compiled your kernel? The time stamp is generated somewhere in the middle of the compilation process, so it may be a few seconds or minutes before the dates of the final files.

Comment: Quote: `my changes aren't showing up in the log files`: Did you boot to the kernel you complied? Was the kernel you complied shown in your bootloader's menu(`/boot/grub2/grub.cfg`)? I have no Ubuntu currently, I remember that you have to install something before you invoke `make install` (https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Kernel/Compile/) Also you can try a full build: `make && make modules_install && make install && echo $?`